# Customise / Customize biber bibliography output

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to adapt bibliography to display in the same way as the style given from college.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
This is a little example for the question \parencite{ctan}.
    Available at: <url to the website>

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This looks like : 
[image]

This is how it's meant to look :

```
Surname, In (YEAR) Italic title of the webpage[Online] [Accessed on: Dayth Month Year]
```

Image example :

[image]

---

I'm not sure how to go about customising this to match, I can't seem to find any other templates that use this style of Harvard referencing to use. I may not really know what to search for though.

Thanks

Comment: I have edited your code to make it compilable without extra files.

Comment: In was guessing on the `style=authoryear`, though. So if the set-up above differs significantly from what you have in your actual document, please change the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your strings are not the standard strings we need to change the standard via

```
\NewBibliographyString{onlinesource}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {accessed on},
  urlfrom = {available at},
  onlinesource = {online},
}
```

where we also add the new "Online" string.

Then what you want can be done via some reformatting of the `url` and `urldate` formats ...

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibsentence\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibsentence\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space<\url{#1}>}
```

... and a slight rework in the order of the macro `url+urldate`.

```
\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{onlinesource}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}%
  \usebibmacro{url}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{onlinesource}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {accessed on},
  urlfrom = {available at},
  onlinesource = {online},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibsentence\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibsentence\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space<\url{#1}>}

\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{onlinesource}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}%
  \usebibmacro{url}}


\begin{document}
This is a little example for the question \parencite{ctan}.
    Available at: <url to the website>

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, how much time did you spent on this answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Roughly the time between my edit of the question (~15 mins ago) and posting the answer (~5 mins ago), so that would be 10 minutes. I probably should have invested more time in looking for a duplicate though.

Comment: Would have taken me longer. btw, if you could have a look at http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html and its dev branch at https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse and maybe give some feedback, i would be more than thankful.

Comment: thanks a lot @moewe, I've realised that I formatted the OP pretty stupidly, but I'll leave it as it is now as somehow you've answered the original question with the `available at : ` underneath the parencite. Thanks :)

Comment: @Johannes_B For lack of a better place, I will comment on your "Wichtige Hinweise" here. I would add a more prominent warning about the fact that the German translation of the biblatex documentation is outdated (the one I found was about version 1.6). While lots of it is still relevant (especially the "basic" stuff), it can be hard to know which bits have changed and even more so for beginners. Since you seem to favour not dropping the last comma after a field in `.bib` files (I agree with you there), you might want  to adjust `kurtGolatexBibTest` example so this practice is uniformly applied.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm curious why you discourage using the `filecontents` package (I quite like its `filecontents*` overwriting features, it allows one to edit included `.bib` files quickly). The real problem is not the way these guides are written, but the fact that too few people actually read them.

Comment: I use filecontents on a very regular basis, but users have the habit of calling stuff `bibliography.bib` in an example and overwriting their real use case bibliography. Dropping `filecontents` *and* using a real unique name for the test document should ensure that nothing goes wrong.

Comment: btw, we could move this to the chat, if more stuff arises.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ahhh, I see (I thought there was some obscure technical reason I was not aware of). Will do that if I can think of more.

Comment: Out of interest, did you answer `biblatex` related posts at goLaTeX today? ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Am I that easily recognisable?

Comment: It was just a wild guess. :-)