# Biblatex : What is the name of the string containing "[online]"?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, strings, online

I am writing a document in French using Biblatex with the iso-numeric style.
I need to translate `[online]` into French, but I didn't find the corresponding string in the documentation. Does anyone know how this string is called?

[image: PDF file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is called `online` [since now](https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/commit/6683f2e0bca027369fb1e0fe2855e1cb942f04c8) in `biblatex-iso690` package. It was changed from a hard-coded string to a bibstring. It obviously takes some time this change will be available through CTAN or your TeX distribution, however you can use a developer version via its [GitHub repository biblatex-iso690](https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690) and if you feel gutsy, you can contribute the French translation into the master branch to be available for everyone. Quick translation guideline is available at [wiki page](https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/wiki/Translation-Guideline).

Answer (score 2):

**This answer became outdated on 2020-01-23. For a current answer see [Dávid Lupták's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/205873/d%c3%a1vid-lupt%c3%a1k)!**

That string is actually hard-coded into `iso.bbx` which is part of `biblatex-iso690`. You can change it by changing the definitions using it:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{t03,
  author       = {LYNCH, C.},
  year         = {2005},
  title        = {Where do we go from here?},
  subtitle     = {the next decade for digital libraries},
  journaltitle = {DLib Magazine},
  volume       = {11},
  number       = {7/8},
  urldate      = {2005-08-15},
  url          = {http://www.dlib.org/dlib/july05/lynch/07lynch.html},
  issn         = {1082-9873},
  langid       = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=iso-numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand*\myonlinetranslation{OnLiNe}


%% copied from `iso.bbx`, altered to use `\myonlinetranslation`
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{howpublished}{%
  \iffieldundef{howpublished}
    {\mkbibbrackets{\myonlinetranslation}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
}
\newbibmacro*{medium-type}{%
  \iffieldundef{howpublished}
    {\iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\myonlinetranslation}}}}
    {\printfield{howpublished}}%
}

\begin{document}
\cite{t03}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this for every document written in French, without having to re-code it each time?

Comment: @GuillaumeFaye-Bédrin you could put this code into a file and place that file in your user texmf so that it becomes findable for every project. Then you could do `\input{<yourfilechangingonline>}` in your preambles and would be done for that project. Or you create a copy of the entire `.bbx` file and place it in your user texmf and correct it therein. Then it would be changed in every project compiled by your user. You can find the file by running `kpsewhich iso.bbx` in your shell.

Comment: See also https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/pull/74#discussion_r368213266

Comment: I recommend a bibstring instead of a simple macro. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238926/35864

Comment: @moewe for the sake of simplicity and as a quick-fix putting a bibstring there doesn't make much sense. This is what the package should have done, like you said, but not something a user has to do for himself, imho.